# CrossCompile Mono for Arm926-EJS

Tags: mono, arm, cross-compiling

I have an arm board and would like to run mono on it...

```
 ~ # cat /proc/cpuinfo
     Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
     BogoMIPS        : 131.48
     Features        : swp half fastmult edsp java
     CPU implementer : 0x41
     CPU architecture: 5TEJ
     CPU variant     : 0x0
     CPU part        : 0x926
     CPU revision    : 5
```

And cross compiler gcc 3.3.4 with uclibc.

Does anyone has any idea if this is even enough to crosscompile mono... It is a Armv5 so ?
Did anyone succeed to build mono for similar configuration? Can you please give me configuration instructions for cross compilation?

Thank you!

Comment: There are [lots of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barm%5D+mono) or just [tags arm and mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm+mono). Cross compiling is not easy; certainly it is possible. Will it run fast? Will it be useable? Do you refuse to write/patch the mono code? Why can't you upgrade your compiler and library? If that is too hard to upgrade your libc and compiler, then maybe making mono on ARM is too hard. A lot of the same concepts will apply.  No one will be able to answer without knowing what filesystem builder you use. Mono will depend on other packages.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:ARM), it will not work out of the box (or scratchbox); none of the supported platforms seem to be an arm926.  The page looks dated as *Maemo* is not well supported afaik.

Comment: well the problem is that i have no option to update the platform as it is very custom created but would like to run mono :S even if it is somewhere in 2.x release

Comment: IS there anywhere written what are the minimum GCC and glib etc.. for a version of mono. Cannot find which version of mono could be built using gcc 3.3.4

Comment: I have the same difficulties. did you manage to build mono for this arm ?

Comment: Gave up :D sorry... Simply compiler was to old